# Twitter Bootstrap: Accordion plugin collides with Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, accordion

I was faced with a problem when using an accordion in the pop-up modal (all are Twitter Bootstrap plugins).
Modal has closed whenever any accordion block was toggled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accordion collapse fires a 'hidden' event, which is actual for Modal plugin too. So, there is a way to prevent modal closing:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.accordion-toggle', function(e) {
    $(e.target).parent().siblings('.accordion-body').on('hidden', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Hope hat helps you.

Comment: Almost worked. I have 2 items in my accordion (which is in a modal) and when I first open the modal and then click on the second item (which is hidden by default) my modal still closes.

Comment: Do you have any tags inside a.accordion-toggle? If Yes, you should bind the stopPropagation event to it too.

Comment: I figured it out already, forgot to remove the html tags. But thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: @JuliaCesar Your answer did not work for me but it pointed me to a solution:
`$('.collapse').on('hidden', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: @WilsonFreitas Your solution is sufficiently optimal! :)

Comment: I also had to add a handler for the 'shown' event, because I was getting duplicated modal 'shown' events.  I've often found with Bootstrap that you're better off writing your own JS and just using their nice styling

Comment: @WilsonFreitas, that works a treat. Post it as an answer. OP should then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

@JuliaCesar Your answer did not work for me but it pointed me to a solution:

```
$('.collapse').on('hidden', function(e){ 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```